# Sorting : Is this performance difference for real or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, sorting

I needed to sort a lot of little arrays composed of 8 floats. Originally I was using std::sort but unhappy with its performance, I tried a compare-swap algorithm generated by this: http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html

test code is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
bool PredDefault(const T &a, const T &b) {return a > b;}

template <typename T>
bool PredDefaultReverse(const T &a, const T &b) {return a < b;}

template <typename T>
void Sort8(T* Data, bool(*pred)(const T &a, const T &b) = PredDefault) {
    #define Cmp_Swap(a, b) if (pred(Data[a], Data[b])) {T tmp = Data[a]; Data[a] = Data[b]; Data[b] = tmp;}

    Cmp_Swap(0, 1); Cmp_Swap(2, 3); Cmp_Swap(4, 5); Cmp_Swap(6, 7);
    Cmp_Swap(0, 2); Cmp_Swap(1, 3); Cmp_Swap(4, 6); Cmp_Swap(5, 7);
    Cmp_Swap(1, 2); Cmp_Swap(5, 6); Cmp_Swap(0, 4); Cmp_Swap(3, 7); 
    Cmp_Swap(1, 5); Cmp_Swap(2, 6);  
    Cmp_Swap(1, 4); Cmp_Swap(3, 6);
    Cmp_Swap(2, 4); Cmp_Swap(3, 5);
    Cmp_Swap(3, 4);

}

int lastTick;
int tick() {
    int hold = lastTick;
    lastTick = GetTickCount();
    return lastTick - hold;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<float>> rVec(1000, vector<float>(8)); 
    for (auto &v : rVec) {
        v[0] = ((float)rand()) * 0.001;
        v[1] = ((float)rand()) * 0.001;
        v[2] = ((float)rand()) * 0.001;
        v[3] = ((float)rand()) * 0.001;
        v[4] = ((float)rand()) * 0.001;
        v[5] = ((float)rand()) * 0.001;
        v[6] = ((float)rand()) * 0.001;
        v[7] = ((float)rand()) * 0.001;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    tick();

    for (int n = 0; n < 50000; n++)
    for (int j = 0; j < rVec.size(); j++) {
        std::sort(rVec[j].begin(), rVec[j].end(), PredDefault<float>);
        std::sort(rVec[j].begin(), rVec[j].end(), PredDefaultReverse<float>);
        //Sort8(rVec[j].data(), PredDefault<float>);
        //Sort8(rVec[j].data(), PredDefaultReverse<float>);
    }

    cout << "\nTime: " << tick() << "\n";
    system("PAUSE");

    return 1;
}
```

add/remove comment marks when testing one or the other.

I wasn't expecting much but the difference is 10x in favor of the swapping sort thing(testing done in release configuration on vs2012 with energy savings stuff turned off). The results check out too. Is this right?

Comment: What you measure is the compiler ability to optimize inline code. On 8 elements, the brute-force compare-and-swap approach might well be more efficient than the generic recursive (and as such difficult to inline) quicksort algorithm from `std::sort`.

Comment: Do your unit tests indicate that it delivers correct results?

Comment: `std::sort` may be such that its least optimal case is when the data starts off reversed

Comment: You're going to be hard pressed to beat a static sorting network implementation for a fixed segment, in particular if your compiler is given liberty to perform parallel operations concurrently. Unrelated, I may have misread, but the static sequence you're using doesn't seem to match what I would have expected from any of the standard sort-net generators, so you may way to verify it is correct and document in your question which algorithm was chosen.

Comment: Microsoft std::sort() will use insertion sort if less than 32 elements are involved.

Comment: @WhozCraig according to the generator its based on the Bose-Nelson algorithm, order optimized for parallel execution(all though, I'm not doing that right now), the results are indeed correct

Comment: @user81993 ok, i was looking at the actual SWAP generation, you were coding on the SVG. No worries. I see how you did it now. Thanks for including the generation selection. Much apprec.

Comment: You've loop-unrolled quicksort. Which indeed makes it much easier for the compiler to optimise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of reasons I can think right off.

1. You have hard coded comparisons. This helps in pipe-lining multiple instructions, which makes it highly efficient. But imagine coding it for N=1000. You'll have to write 1000*1000 comparisons.
2. `std::sort` does `O(nlogn)` comparisons. But this Big O notations holds for large N as the constant of notation can be large. So you can't judge the efficient by running on range of 8 values.